# Filter from Cassandra table by RDD values

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, rdd

I'd like to query some data from Cassandra based on values I have in an RDD. My approach is the following:

```
val userIds = sc.textFile("/tmp/user_ids").keyBy( e => e ) 
val t = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "users").select("userid", "user_name") 
val userNames = userIds.flatMap { userId => 
  t.where("userid = ?", userId).take(1) 
} 
userNames.take(1)
```

While the Cassandra query works in Spark shell, it throws an exception when I used it inside flatMap:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: 
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.<init>(RDD.scala:125) 
        com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.<init>(CassandraRDD.scala:49) 
        com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.copy(CassandraRDD.scala:83) 
        com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.where(CassandraRDD.scala:94)
```

My understanding is that I cannot produce an RDD (Cassandra results) inside another RDD.

The examples I found on the web read the whole Cassandra table in an RDD and join RDDs 
(like this: https://cassandrastuff.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/cassandra-and-spark-table-joins/). But it won't scale if the Cassandra table is huge.

But how do I approach this problem instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Spark 1.2 or Greater

Spark 1.2 introduces `joinWithCassandraTable`

```
val userids = sc.textFile("file:///Users/russellspitzer/users.list")
userids
 .map(Tuple1(_))
 .joinWithCassandraTable("keyspace","table")
```

This code will end up doing the identical work that the solution below
does. The `joinWithCassandraTable` method will use the same code as the
`saveToCassandra` uses to transform classes into something that Cassandra can
understand. This is why we need a tuple
rather than just a simple string to perform the join.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable

---

I think what you actually want to do here is do an inner join on the two datasources. This should actually be faster than a flatmap approach as well as there is some internal smart hashing.

```
scala> val userids = sc.textFile("file:///Users/russellspitzer/users.list")
scala> userids.take(5)
res19: Array[String] = Array(3, 2)

scala> sc.cassandraTable("test","users").collect
res20: Array[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = Array(CassandraRow{userid: 3, username: Jacek}, CassandraRow{userid: 1, username: Russ}, CassandraRow{userid: 2, username: Helena})

scala> userids.map(line => (line.toInt,true)).join(sc.cassandraTable("test","users").map(row => (row.getInt("userid"),row.getString("username")))).collect
res18: Array[(Int, (Boolean, String))] = Array((2,(true,Helena)), (3,(true,Jacek)))
```

If you actually just want to execute a bunch of primary key queries against your C* database you may be better off just executing them using normal driver pathways and not using spark.

### Spark Solution Integrating with Direct Driver Calls

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import collection.JavaConversions._

val cc = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
val select = s"SELECT * FROM cctest.users where userid=?"
val ids = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
ids.flatMap(id =>
      cc.withSessionDo(session =>
        session.execute(select, id.toInt: java.lang.Integer).iterator.toList.map(row =>
          (row.getInt("userid"), row.getString("username"))))).collect
```