# writetime of cassandra row in spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

i'm using spark with cassandra, and i want to select from my cassandra table the writeTime of my row. This is my request :

```
   val lines = sc.cassandraTable[(String, String, String, Long)](CASSANDRA_SCHEMA, table).select("a", "b", "c", "writeTime(d)").count()
```

but it display this error :

```
java.io.IOException: Column channal not found in table test.mytable
```

I've tried also this request

```
   val lines = sc.cassandraTable[(String, String, String, Long)](CASSANDRA_SCHEMA, table).select("a", "b", "c", WRITETIME("d")").count()
```

but it display this error :

```
<console>:25: error: not found: value WRITETIME
```

Please how can i get the writeTime of my row. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit: This has been fixed in the 1.2 release of the connector

Currently the Connector doesn't support passing through CQL functions when reading from Cassandra. I've taken note of this and will start up a ticket for implementing this functionality.

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-55

For a workaround you can always use the direct connector within your operations like in

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector

val cc = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
val select = s"SELECT WRITETIME(userId) FROM cctest.users where userid=?"
val ids = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
ids.flatMap(id =>
      cc.withSessionDo(session =>
        session.execute(select, id.toInt: java.lang.Integer)
```

Code modified from
[Filter from Cassandra table by RDD values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121934/filter-from-cassandra-table-by-rdd-values/28122431#28122431)

Comment: is there a possibility to parallelize my ResultSet ?

Answer (score 4):

In cassandra-spark-connector 1.2, you can get TTL and write time by writing:

```
sc.cassandraTable(...).select("column1", WriteTime("column2"), TTL("column3"))
```

Comment: can I do the same in python? since I got an error as NameError: name 'WriteTime' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-8) ticket.

For usage, take a look at integration tests [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/it/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraRDDSpec.scala#L483).