# Fetch column writeTime in DataSet using spark cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to figure out if I can fetch column writeTime using spark cassandra connector when trying to load cassandra data into a DataSet (DataFrame)

This is what I am trying to do:

```
val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
   .options(Map( "table" -> "table1", "keyspace" -> "keyspace1",
           "cluster" -> "cluster1")).load()
```

I want to fetch a bunch of columns and writeTimes into a DataFrame:

```
val someColumns = df.select("column_a", "column_b", 
       "column_c", "column_a".writeTime)
```

Unfortunately, something "column_a".writeTime is not supported. Does anyone know any alternative for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504250/writetime-of-cassandra-row-in-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support in Dataset API for ttl and writeTime yet.
You can create RDD and then convert the RDD to DF:

```
val df = sc.cassandraTable[(Option[String], Option[Long])]("ks", "table").
      select ("name",  "name".writeTime).toDF()
```